# Schengen visa refusal for visitor visa - possible resolution?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

My husband is in Switzerland for 6 months with L permit.  I applied for visitor visa.  I submitted all documents with his entrance visa in which date of his coming back to India was not mentioned but later on after submission of visa documents to VFS office, I submitted his L-permit through mail.  But my visa got rejected stating **" your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of visa could not be ascertained".**

I also got confused on the answer of extension of my husbands visa permit during answering to the embassy council.

I have only 7 days left to reapply for visa.  I don't know what should I do? 
Will I able to get visa again within 7 working  days??

Comment: I am trying to get visitor visa for first time to go there.

Comment: They seem to be worried that you'd go to Switzerland to visit your husband and stay. Did you include any evidence to show why you would return home after the visit? Is there anything you could include to show that which you didn't?

Comment: And also..I submitted my husband's L-Permit later on email after submitting all documents to visa office..Is this can be the reason?

Comment: My concern is--   1- Will I be able to get visa in 7 working days if I submit all documents?   2- How would I know what additional document they require as Embassy councellor is unreachable?

Comment: I don't know about Switzerland in particular, but as a general rule I don't think you'd have much luck with submitting a new set of documents and having them processed in only 7 days. Have you thought about going to Dubai? It's half way so you'd split the flying, and I believe it's easy for you to get a visa to go

Comment: I am so sorry to hear this. You should reapply and be better prepared in case you are called for an interview. What they expect in case of a visitor visa (especially from citizens of third world countries) is an obligation to return to your country. You have to show some kind of proof that you are on leave from your work or study. In case you are unemployed, you need to show proof of your permanent residency. Also, it will help if you show your confirmed return ticket.

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule, when deciding on whether to issue a non-work visa to someone, two things will be considered. One is if you're likely to be problem during the trip, the other is if you're likely to neglect to leave afterwards. To satisfy them on the former, you're often asked to show you have the funds to support yourself, have hotels booked, are of good character etc. For the latter, a return ticket is generally a must, but more may be required depending on your situation.

Based on your rejection, it seems that the Swiss authorities are concerned about the second part. They worry that you will fly out to see your husband on a short stay tourist visa, and then stay. (I've known people have the same rejection reason who work in IT, and are wanting to attend a conference). Sadly, coming from somewhere like India, and having your husband be in Switzerland will make you seem like a high risk candidate.

If you want to appeal the decision / re-apply, you're going to need to show that you have every intention of leaving at the end. (Ideally that should have been in your initial application, it'll be harder now because you didn't include it then). You'll need to find some way to demonstrate you won't just stay with your husband. That could include family back home, a stable job to return to, study courses you're part way through, proof of property owning / long term renting etc. If you can't find enough evidence to convince them that you'll leave, you won't get the visa...

Also, in the comments you asked about timescales. Some countries and some visa classes have targets and guarantees for issuing times (while others it can take a long time). However, generally appeals and second applications are excluded from these, so expect those to take longer, sometimes much longer. Unless your initial application was processed in under 2 days, I'd say it'd be a pretty long shot to get a reconsideration/appeal processed in under 7 days

Comment: I re-applied for visitor visa.
This time I also included-
1- my husband's comany letter that he will be coming back on May'2013 bcoz he has to join India office from june.
2- his supportive letter
3- my undertaking letter
and all required docs

but again my visa got refused with the same reason... :(
my husband is there for more 3 months.
what should he do-
1- appleal
2- apply for dependant visa..

pathetic experience with Swiss embassy..

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can file a [Written Objection](http://www.vfs-ch-in.com/images/Formaldecision16.03.12.pdf) but as the document says the decision time on the Objection could take from 6 to 12 weeks.

It is very likely that the decision will not be in your favor unless you have a really compelling reason to stay.  You could contact the embassy to try and expedite it.

Comment: My concern is-- 1- Will I be able to get visa in 7 working days if I submit all documents? 2- How would I know what additional document they require as Embassy councellor is unreachable?

Comment: @user4490 1. Noone except the consular workers will be able to answer that question, since you've already got a rejection once.  2. If any additional documentation is required you will be told but any such documentation such as letters of invitation should be submitted with the Objection.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply but I was not told about additional documents thats why I am confused and keep guessing what could be reason..

Comment: @user4490 What could be the reason for refusal?  Or what could be the reason for not telling you about necessity of additional documentation?

Comment: @Karlson the reason for refusal is the extreme risk she'll just "stay with her husband" (using quotes as there are way too many fake marriages used by people from Asia to get into the EU on tourist visas, apply for permanent status while there, then get a divorce the moment that's issued). If they're not telling her, most likely there's nothing she can do to change that decision, meaning an appeal is pointless. Best they can do is meet up in a 3rd country outside the EU.

Comment: @jwenting OP is stating she is confused, so I'd like to know about what.

Comment: @Karlson that seems an unrelated question she doesn't give further information on. Reads like her husband?'s visa extension request also got denied, maybe in part as a result of the denial of her application causing questions to be raised as to his legitimacy.

Comment: @jwenting I've learned not to make assumptions like this.

Comment: I re-applied for visitor visa.
This time I also included-
1- my husband's comany letter that he will be coming back on May'2013 bcoz he has to join India office from june.
2- his supportive letter
3- my undertaking letter
and all required docs

but again my visa got refused with the same reason... :(
my husband is there for more 3 months.
what should he do-
1- appleal
2- apply for dependant visa..

pathetic experience with Swiss embassy..