# Refused visit a friend visa for Belgium

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, belgium, filipino-citizens

I applied for a [visa to visit a friend](http://www.diplomatie.be/manila/default.asp?id=28&ACT=5&content=12&mnu=28) in Belgium last April 28, 2014 and I got the result recently (June 6, 2014) wherein it has been refused.

Reasons were:

1. The plan and the circumstances from the intend stay are insufficient.
2. Resolve to leave country before end of visa couldn't be determined.
3. No med-travel insurance.

I'm a Filipino citizen and applied from Manila. My boyfriend is sponsoring me. We were confident that I should be able to get the visa, because we both know that we have completed and submitted all the requirements that are needed for the visa. I wanted to appeal the refusal of my visa.

What are my options? I haven't yet received the official result of my refusal and will be going to the Belgium Embassy in Manila as per the schedule they have given me.

What sort of letter can I do to assist my situation?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20849/26 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13618/26

Comment: You should receive a standard form notifying the refusal in writing and a document detailing the procedure to appeal the decision (all Schengen member states have to provide such a procedure). I am afraid there isn't much to do before that.

Comment: A pleasant evening to you aditya, By the way i forgot to tell you that i will be going to Manila next week Tuesday June 17, to get my passport back also the letter why i got refused. Thank you so much again. i will keep you posted as soon as i already have the result.

Comment: @sha Could you add the reason of refusal to your question? Also, why don't you just call them. That way you know exactly what documents to bring and safe you a second trip.

Comment: @AdityaSomani: Hi Aditya, how are you? I went to manila last Tuesday to pick up the letter why my visa got refused and its all written i Dutch. My boyfriend tried his best to translate the reason why my visa got refused. and this is there reason  a) The plan and the circumstances from the intend stay are insufficient. b)Resolve to leave country before end of visa couldn't be determine
No med-travel insurance

Comment: @PeterRaeves: Hi Sir Peter, here are the reasons why i got refused..a) The plan and the circumstances from the intend stay are insufficient. b)Resolve to leave country before end of visa couldn't be determine c)No med-travel insurance

Comment: @sha b and c shouldn't be too difficult to solve. If you buy a return ticket to the Fillipines and get medical-travel insurance then those problems are fixed. I'm not sure what a) means. Why don't you give the embassy a call or visit and ask them what you need to do in order to fix that problem?

Comment: @sha You should add this information to your question for further information. I'll take a detailed look and see if I can come up with something. Cheers!

Comment: @AdityaSomani: Hi, i have made my letter of appeal, only one thing again i am confused, if where i could send it, i don't know which address. oh my, oh my, so stressed now.. :-(

Comment: @sha Did they not provide you with any instructions on how to proceed?

Comment: @PeterRaeves:I just couldn't buy it, it was strictly written on the requirements of visit visa that: Please read this.NOTE : You may also be required to submit additional documents at the discretion of the Visa Officer. 
Remark : In case of approval, applicants have to produce an original medical and travel insurance valid for all Schengen countries issued by a Philippine or European insurance company (+ 1 photocopy). This insurance should cover a minimum of 30,000 Euros and should cover the validity of the visa

Comment: @PeterRaeves: also about the plane ticket..IMPORTANT
The Embassy of Belgium does not require a plane ticket to be submitted when lodging the application. simple reservation is enough.

Comment: @AdityaSomani: They gave us the refusal letter and it was written in dutch, my Boyfriend tried his best to translate it in english, but its so confusing though.:-(

Comment: @sha You should try taking the help of google translate or posting a separate question on Travel.SE ragarding the letter. Make the most of your resources! :D

Comment: @AdityaSomani: i am trying my best, everything i need to know i try to google it.. Thank you so much again, :-)

Comment: Most important is to convince the consulate you are not going to stay in Belgium. Anything that shows some ties to the Philippines (Do you have a job? Family there? Are registered at a university?) could be useful (but it might not be enough at this point).

Comment: @sha do you have a job in the Philippines?

Comment: @Relaxed: I am trying my best to convinced and made a appeal about the refusal of my application. My Bf And i were hoping and Praying that we can hear a good news from the said council.. And YES, i have a Job here in the Philippines.., Thank you for the concern :-)

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Yes, i have a job here in the Philippines..

Answer (score 1):

It's common for embassies to get nervous when your reason is to visit family / spouse / significant other, as sometimes this is what overstayers do - find a way in, and then just don't leave.  Therefore, your job is to assure them that:

1. You're not overstaying
2. You're just visiting your significant other
3. You have money to cover your time there
4. You have a return ticket booked
5. You have valid medical insurance to cover your time there, so that you won't be a medical problem for their country

To prove you're not trying to overstay and are just visiting, you simply print out your plane tickets showing your return.  If you have evidence that you're working or studying at home, a letter from your employer showing you're returning to work at a given date will help, or your uni showing the upcoming courses you're involved in.

You'll also need to print bank statements showing your current balance to show you've considered how to cover your time there.  If you've only got say, $200 and are planning to stay at the best hotels when asked, it'll raise flags. They're just making sure you don't get into financial difficulty while there.

Also make sure you get medical insurance, or show intent to get it (reserved funds) and print that out, showing that you're covered for the duration of the trip.

Finally if you have an itinerary (are travelling while there) write it out, so that you can clearly show what your intended journey is, how much it might cost, and so on.  A budget may even help! (Not normally required, but at this point, more documentation is good to help convince them).

You said you were confident you'd completed all requirements, but the letter clearly indicates you're missing a few things, so hopefully with the above items covered your next application will go more smoothly, and you can enjoy a trip to Belgium!

Comment: Hi there, Thank you about this warm response. Yes i do understand also about the embassy's concern. Also one more thing they told me, that i did ask for 85 days of visit, and this is my first time to visit the country(Belgium). Also they said i am young and never been married, they thought that i might get married to my Bf when i get there..

Comment: :Also they gave meaning on the other document, that i have submitted, its My authenticated birth certificate, again they said that this papers is not for short stay,they assumed that i want to stay longer after my visa expires.also they said i am young and not yet married (but i am 32 already) i might marry my boyfriend when i get there.. Travel medical insurance should be passed upon the approval of the visa..