# Does renewing passports have an impact on the visa process, if previously I was refused?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

I was refused twice for a student visa by the German embassy 3 years ago.

I applied for a tourist visa at the same embassy, but they again refused and in the refused letter they mentioned reason no#9.

I appealed and again they refused.

Now I have three refusals already linked with my passport.

My question is, if I plan to travel in the future will these three refusals hurt my chances for obtaining visas?

Specifically, **can I improve my chances by renewing my passport?**

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: No idea what are you asking

Comment: i am bangladeshi. i am afraid with my passport which have 3 times refused seal.  should i issue a new passport for my future tour in schengen country? pls help me

Comment: What is reason number 9?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's “your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of visa could not be ascertained” (thanks for the edit, btw)

Comment: I edited the question to is hopefully makes more sense, and should stop the downvote flood.

Comment: The passport renewal aspect has been answered (don't do it!). Regarding the reason for the refusal and how to address it, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/schengen-visa-refusal-for-visitor-visa-possible-resolution

Comment: @Ashraf I see you have posted an answer there so you obviously know about http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-can-a-visa-refusal-affect-my-future-travel-plans You need to read that page very carefully because it mostly answers your current question. Nobody will be able to tell you more than that, predict how your next application will go, or tell you there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a new *passport* should make no difference at all. To get your tourist visa application granted, you have to convince the embassy that you are coming as a tourist, that you will stay for tourism only, and that you will leave again at the end of your holiday.

- Are your travel plans reasonable for a tourist? Do you have a reasonable appreciation how much living costs in Germany while one is traveling? Do you have a round trip ticket? Medical insurance covering the trip?
- Can you convince the embassy that you're not an economic migrant, e.g. by showing that you have a steady, well-paid job at home? This also ties into the first question, can you show that you can afford the trip?

Comment: thanks to all for giving your advice. yes,  i submitted my invitation letter from my sister who live in germany.

Comment: @Ashraf, that explains how you plan to pay for your stay, but it makes it even more important to show that you will go back after your holiday.

Comment: yes. i submitted all supporting documents.  invitation letter from my sister who live in germany. insurence for  one month cover. bank statement with last balance 6000 euro. returned ticket reservation.  job leave paper. my land property papers. and my stay was not more then two weeks.

Answer (score 2):

As o.m. already wrote, getting a new passport would not help at all but he or she forgot the most important reason: Your previous applications have all been recorded in a database so any other Schengen consulate (not only in your current country of residence, and not only from Germany) can and will very easily find out about them. Changing your passport without credible reason might actually make your application look even worse as it signals an intent to deceive.

Beyond that, there is nothing stopping you from applying again and in theory previous refusals do not legally lead to automatic refusal of a new application but if your plans and your situation haven't changed, there is no reason to expect a different outcome. Furthermore, if you have offered a different purpose for the trip in your last applications (how would you expect a new application to succeed otherwise?), changing your story all the time and collecting refusals do not make you look like a reliable applicant to the consulate.

Also, if you have already got three refusals and a failed appeal, you obviously have very weak applications. You might need to get help from a real lawyer and work very hard to improve your situation to even have a fighting chance at getting a visa, simple tricks like renewing a passport are not going to help.

Comment: I am not sure, but repeated applications _may_ have an impact (even if not specifically prescribed in the guidelines) just as a matter of curiosity by the officer - if a person is trying repeatedly with the same reason, it wouldn't surprise me if that alone raised a few eyebrows.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Theoretically and legally, it works slightly differently. If a visa is refused, it has to be because some requirement (including the intent to leave the country in time and otherwise respect the conditions of the visa) is currently unmet. Of course, consular officers know about previous applications and it might influence their evaluation of an applicant's intent so it definitely could have an impact.

Comment: Agreed, my point was that legally they are required to reject based on a specific reason (and not arbitrarily, which helps both the counselor and the applicant) but in the end the officer is most likely trained to detect patterns of such repeated applications (if just to detect fraudulent/false applications) and I am sure such things factor into their overall decision.